# При вызове класса и метода ошибка - Main.cpp:4:13: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token 4 |

Tags: c++, ооп

Код:

Application.cpp

```
Application :: Init() 

{

Window.ShowWindow();

}
```

Application.hpp:

```
#include "Window.hpp"

class Application {

public:
    bool Init();
};
```

Window.hpp:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

 extern bool Start_Successed = NULL;

 class Window {

 public:
    bool ShowWindow(unsigned int width = 800, unsigned int height = 600, 
                                                      const char*title = "Welcome!");
   };
```

Window.cpp:

```
#include "Window.hpp"

Window :: ShowWindow(unsigned int width = 800, unsigned int height = 600, const char* 
                                                 title = "Welcome!") {

 bool Start_Successed = NULL;

 GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (glfwInit())
    Start_Successed = true;

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    Start_Successed = true;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Render here */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwTerminate();

return Start_Successed;
```

}

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Application.hpp"

int main(void) {
Application().Init();
```

}

Comment: Не вижу причину в `Main`, но в `Application.cpp` - неправильно записали функцию. Надо добавить возвращаемый тип и `return` в конце.

Comment: В `Window :: ShowWindow` тоже возвращаемый тип не написали..